# Why my text is not displaying in the center?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I started playing with react-native and I got a problem with centering a text, it's a very simple code but idk why it's not working

I was playing with animations too and none of all the examples that I did didn't work

So I have a View with a Text and the styles, with the flex should be enought, but isn't

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeView extends Component {

      render(){  
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Hello World</Text>
          </View>     
        );
      }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
     welcome: {
       fontSize: 20,
       textAlign: 'center',
       margin: 10
     }
});
```

Here is the App class

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View} from 'react-native';
import HomeView from './components/HomeView';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <HomeView/>
    </View>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

});

export default App;
```

And the index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: You need to use export default. Can you show picture of error after you use export default?

Comment: @crodev don't consider this, I was using two times export default

Comment: Can you show me your imports?

Comment: @crodev I posted all the code, and yes, I'm closing render()

Comment: Can you show me where are you using <HomeView/>? Is it used as component in some other component, or navigation etc.

Comment: yess, edited with all the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the App class you need to render the View with container style
so it would be

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <HomeView/>
    </View>

  );
};
```

so it has `flex: 1` and then  can take the full space and align itself properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your class with `}` after render().